# Alternative to items being left in queue (threaded consumer-producer)

Tags: c#, multithreading, queue, async-await, task-parallel-library

As part of a library using [this code](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/damianh/Obsolete-Cedar/master/src/Cedar.GetEventStore/Handlers/ResolvedEventDispatcher.cs), there is a `SimpleQueue` class to decouple the producer from consumer:

```
private class SimpleQueue
{
    private readonly Func<ResolvedEvent, CancellationToken, Task> _onResolvedEvent;
    private readonly CancellationToken _token;
    private readonly ConcurrentQueue<ResolvedEvent> _events;
    private readonly InterlockedBoolean _isPushing;
    private static readonly ILog s_logger;

    static SimpleQueue()
    {
        s_logger = LogProvider.For<SimpleQueue>();
    }

    public SimpleQueue(Func<ResolvedEvent, CancellationToken, Task> onResolvedEvent, CancellationToken token)
    {
        _onResolvedEvent = onResolvedEvent;
        _token = token;
        _events = new ConcurrentQueue<ResolvedEvent>();
        _isPushing = new InterlockedBoolean();
    }

    public void Enqueue(ResolvedEvent resolvedEvent)
    {
        _events.Enqueue(resolvedEvent);
        Push();
    }

    private void Push()
    {
        if(_isPushing.CompareExchange(true, false))
        {
            return;
        }
        Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            ResolvedEvent resolvedEvent;
            while (!_token.IsCancellationRequested && _events.TryDequeue(out resolvedEvent))
            {
                try
                {
                    await _onResolvedEvent(resolvedEvent, _token);
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    s_logger.ErrorException(ex.Message, ex);
                }
            }
            _isPushing.Set(false);
        }, _token);
    }
}
```

I think I can see an issue here, in that if:

1. In the task thread, the call `events.TryDequeue(out resolvedEvent))` returns `false`
2. Then context switches to the other thread
3. In the other thread event is enqueued, `Push()` is called but returns immediately as `_isPushing` is `true`
4. The context switches back to the task thread, `_isPushing` is set to `false` and the task exits

In this case there would be on event in the queue that is not dispatched until the next enqueue and loop in `Push()` to dequeue. If so I don't think I like this.

**So instead i rewrote to use a TPL BlockingQueue:**

```
public class SimpleQueue<T>
{
    readonly BufferBlock<T> _queue = new BufferBlock<T>();

    public SimpleQueue(Func<T, CancellationToken, Task> onItemQueued, CancellationToken token)
    {
        Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            while (true)
            {
                try
                {
                    var item = await _queue.ReceiveAsync(token);
                    if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
                        return;
                    await onItemQueued(item, token);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    // log
                }
            }
        }, token);
    }

    public void Enqueue(T item)
    {
        _queue.Post(item);
    }
}

class Program
{
    private readonly static SimpleQueue<string> Queue;
    private readonly static CancellationToken CancellationToken = new CancellationToken();

    static async Task OnEvent(string item, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Rx from remote {0}", item);

        }, cancellationToken);
    }

    static Program()
    {
        Queue = new SimpleQueue<string>(OnEvent, CancellationToken);
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // wire up code to call ExternalReceive from 3rd party lib
        DevLinkImports.DLRegisterType2CallDeltas(0,CallEvent);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    // this is called by 3rd party dll on demand
    static void CallEvent(uint pbxh, string info)
    {
        // we must dispatch and return within 50ms or 3rd party lib will go ape
        Queue.Enqueue(info);  
    }
```

**Questions:**

1. For learning purposes am I correct in seeing the issue with the original SimpleQueue and items could be left depending on timing?
2. Without "premature optimization" i feel it only sensible to ask, what is the overhead of spinning up a new thread for each call to `static async Task OnEvent(string item, CancellationToken cancellationToken)`?
3. With the rewrite I am not holding threads open when sleeping, but in reality is there any benefit of using this async call or just instead spin up a single thread and use a `BlockingCollection` and blocking on dequeue? I don't want to save one thread for sacrificing time taken to spin up new threads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. For learning purposes am I correct in seeing the issue with the original SimpleQueue and items could be left depending on timing?

Impossible to say for sure, as the implementation for `InterlockedBoolean` has not been provided here. It does seem plausible that your concern is valid, but I would want to see the actual code before trying to make a definitive statement.

> 2. Without "premature optimization" i feel it only sensible to ask, what is the overhead of spinning up a new thread for each call to static async Task OnEvent(string item, CancellationToken cancellationToken)?

The overhead of creating a *new* thread is significant. But your `OnEvent()` method may or may not actually do that. You are creating a new task, which the scheduler then will decide how to dispose of it. If the thread pool contains an available thread to use to execute it and/or the scheduler decides it can wait for an existing-but-busy thread to become available, then no new thread will be created.

> 3. With the rewrite I am not holding threads open when sleeping, but in reality is there any benefit of using this async call or just instead spin up a single thread and use a BlockingCollection and blocking on dequeue? I don't want to save one thread for sacrificing time taken to spin up new threads.

Adding a *single* thread to your program to service the queue is not really all that bad. You'll create it just once, so the overhead for that is inconsequential. It does tie up a megabyte for the stack (by default), but that's usually not going to be a problem either.

On the other hand, likewise calling `Task.Run()` is unlikely to cause significant overhead either, due to the use of the thread pool.

So to me it comes down to aesthetics and maintainability.

I will point out that the question of using `BlockingCollection<T>` vs `BufferBlock<T>` is somewhat different from the question of your implementation of `OnEvent()`. The former concerns the implementation of the underlying queue, while the latter concerns what happens when an event is in fact dequeued. Even if you use `BlockingCollection<T>`, if you don't change `OnEvent()` you're still going to start a new task for every event. Conversely, there's no reason you couldn't make `OnEvent()` run the event handling synchronously, even using `BufferBlock<T>`.

The queue code clearly *expects* the event to be handled asynchronously, but the event doesn't have to be. That's up to the client of the queue.

Comment: This was *very* useful, especially the mention of the worker thread pool being used so a new thread may not necessarily be span up something I had completely overlooked. Given your advice I feel much more comfortable using async.